# With ReactiveCocoa bind to inverse of BOOL

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I would like to do the opposite of the following code:

```
RAC(self.activityIndicator, hidden) = RACObserve(self.playButton, selected);
```

When the play button is selected the activity indicator should be **NOT** hidden.

What is the best way to do this using ReactiveCocoa?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's a signal operator for this, [`-not`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/fc64f9add60be383927c13fd3ff27b0daaa29700/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal%2BOperations.h#L570-574).

```
RAC(self.activityIndicator, hidden) = [RACObserve(self.playButton, selected) not];
```

Answer (score 4):

`map:` is what you need.

```
RAC(self.activityIndicator, hidden) = [RACObserve(self.playButton, selected) map:^id(id value) {
    return @(![value boolValue]);
}];
```

This transforms the signal into another one based on what you return from the map function.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift (v6.2.1) it will look like this:

`var isButtonEnabled =  MutableProperty<Bool>(true)`

`myImageView.reactive.isHidden <~ isButtonEnabled.negate()`